# is it necessary to register app on facebook while using social framework?

Tags: ios, facebook, social-framework, facebook-share

I am using social framework for facebook sharing or post to FB.So my question is for this,do i need to register my app on facebook developer account or can i directly post on facebook without registering my app.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer.For FB Sharing you don't need any kind of registration of app.But for FB login through you need to register your app first with developer account.Please correct me if i am wrong at any point.Anyone who want to add some information is also welcomed.